# Keeping hyphenated layout in code - making it disappear from PDF

Tags: hyphenation, sourcecode

I have an OCRed document that I want to typeset. However, for validation purposes I want to keep the original layout in the code, but make hyphens disappear from the compiled document. Is there a way to achieve this? I tried to insert optional hyphens (`\-`), but the line break still ads an unnecessary space.

Something like:

```
(Aus Pesth, den 11. August.) Die in einigen Zeitblättern
spärlich zerstreuten Nachrichtenüber die Israeliten in Ungarn rüh-
ren allesammt von ununterrichteten Berichterstattern her, welche
ihre Unbekanntschaft mit den bestehenden Verhältnissen fast mit
jedem Worte verrathen. Authentische Nachrichten hierüber dürf-
ten Ihnen nicht unwillkommen sein. Die erste Erwähnung ver-
dient wohl die hiesige, 1467 Familien zählende Gemeinde, nächst
Brody und Prag die größte im Kaiserstaate.
```

But still have in the document *rühren, dürften* and *verdient* without a hyphen or a space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could replace your OCR'd source `-` by `\sourcehyph` defined by

```
\let\sourcehyph\-
```

being a control name of letters it will mean the following line end is absorbed and not make a space in the document, and will ensure that point is still a legal breakpoint to be re-hyphenated.

Using

```
\-%
```

would also work but looks less clear to me, and if you accidentally re-wrap the paragraph you may find yourself commenting out text you did not intend to lose.

Comment: No TeX editor worth its salt will rewrap after a line that ends in a comment.

Comment: @AR-solidarityforModstrike Well I know emacs doesn't. I have heard rumours that other editors exist though, so I was cautious in my phrasing.